# Need to pass object through dynamically created event handler

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, eventhandler

Need to pass object through dynamically created event handler in vb.net application, (newperson is a usercontrol). The event handler:

```
AddHandler newperson.MouseUp, AddressOf newperson_MouseUp
```

Then I use this handler as follows,

```
Private Sub newperson_MouseUp()

End sub
```

But I need to refer to the newperson within this sub, e.g.

```
newperson.Background = Brushes.Black
```

Any input or ideas will be appreciated :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three things:

1. A custom EventArgs class where you store a reference to your newPerson object

   ```
   Public Class MyMouseUpEventArgs
       Inherits MouseEventArgs

   Public Sub New(newPerson As Person, b As MouseButtons, clicks As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer, Delta As Integer)
       MyBase.New(b, clicks, x, y, Delta)
       Me.newPerson = newPerson
   End Sub

   Public Property newPerson As Person
   End Class
   ```

   It inherits from MouseEventArgs to also have the default event args, but this is not a must have.
2. In your custom control you need to handle the original MouseUp event. In this handler you simply raise a new custom event which I called MyMouseUp. This custom event takes as parameter the previously created MyMouseEventArgs with the new person

   ```
   Public Class Person
          Inherits UserControl

   Public Shared Event MyMouseUp(sender As Object, e As MyMouseUpEventArgs)

   Public Sub New()
       AddHandler Me.MouseUp, AddressOf OnMouseUp
   End Sub

   Private Overloads Sub OnMouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
       RaiseEvent MyMouseUp(sender, New MyMouseUpEventArgs(Me, e.Button, e.Clicks, e.X, e.Y, e.Delta))
   End Sub
   End Class
   ```

   The custom event must be shared so it can be used in the handler class without object reference shown in step
3. The handler (here just the main form) now registers to the new custom event with the custom event args. Thus you can access newPerson.

   ```
   Public Class Form1

   Public Sub New()
       InitializeComponent()

       AddHandler Person.MyMouseUp, AddressOf OnyMyMouseUp
   End Sub

   Private Overloads Sub OnyMyMouseUp(sender As Object, e As MyMouseUpEventArgs)
       'Do stuff
       e.newPerson.BackColor = Color.Aqua
   End Sub
   End Class
   ```

Hope that helps. The code is not tested so no warranty is given ;)

Comment: worked almost instantly except from a few very minute errors, massive help thanks :)